Why Tensorflow.js based Weather Prediction Model is unable to predict correct weather
I am learning tensorflow.js and this is perhaps the first full program I am trying to write. However I feel something is wrong. My model is not able to predict right Weather and always predicting 'Haze' no matter how I train it. Following is the sample NodeJS program I am running to train and predict. Please help me figure out what is going wrong here:
// Install the necessary packages:
// npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
const _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

var data = require('./data2.json');

// Sample data (replace with your actual data)
const features = [];
const labels = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    features.push([data[i].temp, data[i].wind, data[i].humidity, data[i].pressure, data[i].visibility, yearToDateTime(data[i].date, data[i].time)]);
    labels.push(data[i].weatherType);
}
var uniqLabels = _.uniq(labels);
(async() => {

    // Create a simple neural network model
    var model = null;
    if (fs.existsSync('./kolkata-weather-model/model.json')) {
        model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://./kolkata-weather-model/model.json');
    }

    if (model == null) {
        model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid', inputShape: [6] }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: uniqLabels.length, activation: 'sigmoid' }));

        // Compile the model
        model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

        // Train the model
        const xs = tf.tensor2d(features);
        const ys = tf.tensor1d(_.map(labels, (o) => { return _.indexOf(uniqLabels, o); }));
        model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 100 }).then(() => {
            model.save('file://./kolkata-weather-model');
            // Example prediction for tomorrow's weather
            getTomorrowPrediction(model);
        });
    } else {
        getTomorrowPrediction(model);
    }
})();

function getTomorrowPrediction(model) {
    const tomorrowFeatures = [10, 2, 35, 1008, 30, yearToDateTime('20240101', '15:30')]; // Replace with actual values
    const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([tomorrowFeatures])).argMax(1).dataSync()[0];
    console.log('Weather prediction for tomorrow:', uniqLabels[prediction]);
}

function yearToDateTime(dt, time) {
    if (!_.isNil(dt) && dt.length == 8 && !_.isNil(time) && time.length == 5) {
        var yr = dt.substring(0, 4);
        var mon = dt.substring(4, 6);
        var day = dt.substring(6);
        var firstDayOfYr = Date.parse(yr + '-01-01 00:00:00.000');
        var todayDate = Date.parse(yr + '-' + mon + '-' + day + ' ' + time + ':00.000');
        return todayDate - firstDayOfYr;
    }
    return -1;
}

function getWeatherTypeName(id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        return 'Sunny';
    } else if (id == 2) {
        return 'Cloudy';
    } else if (id == 3) {
        return 'Rainy';
    } else {
        return 'Unknown';
    }
}

function getWeatherType(weatherType) {
    weatherType = weatherType
        .replace('Cool', 1)
        .replace('Mild', 1)
        .replace('Clear', 1)
        .replace('Fog', 2)
        .replace('Haze', 1)
        .replace('Passing clouds', 2)
        .replace('Partly sunny', 1)
        .replace('Scattered clouds', 2)
        .replace('Drizzle Broken clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Broken clouds', 2)
        .replace('Light rain Partly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Partly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Broken clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Partly cloudy', 2)
        .replace('Warm', 1)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Partly cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Passing clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Broken clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Partly sunny.', 2)
        .replace('Light rain Passing clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Scattered clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Scattered clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms More clouds than sun.', 2)
        .replace('More clouds than sun', 2)
        .replace('Light rain More clouds than sun.', 3)
        .replace('Hot', 1)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Mostly cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Mostly cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Light rain Mostly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Drizzle More clouds than sun.', 3)
        .replace('Drizzle Mostly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Broken clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Mostly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Mostly cloudy', 2)
        .replace('Rain More clouds than sun.', 3)
        .replace('Thundershowers Broken clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Sunny', 1)
        .replace('', '-1')
        .replace('Smoke', 2)
        .replace('Thundershowers Partly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Heavy rain More clouds than sun.', 3)
        .replace('Heavy rain Mostly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms More clouds than sun.', 2)
        .replace('Extremely hot', 1)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Broken clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Rain Scattered clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Heavy rain Broken clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Partly sunny.', 3)
        .replace('Light fog', 1)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Partly cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Rain showers More clouds than sun.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Partly sunny.', 3)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Cloudy.', 2)
        .replace('Rain Passing clouds.', 3)
        .replace('Rain Overcast.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Overcast.', 3)
        .replace('Heavy rain Cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Hail Mostly cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Thunderstorms Overcast.', 2)
        .replace('Overcast', 2)
        .replace('Drizzle Cloudy.', 3)
        .replace('Light rain Fog.', 3)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Scattered clouds.', 2)
        .replace('Cloudy', 2)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Partly sunny.', 2)
        .replace('Strong thunderstorms Passing clouds.', 2);
    return parseInt(weatherType, 10);
}

My data sample is like this which is used for training (data2.json):
[   {
        "date": "20140101",
        "time": "00:20",
        "temp": 14,
        "weatherType": "Cool",
        "wind": null,
        "humidity": 88,
        "pressure": 1016,
        "visibility": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "20200720",
        "time": "21:00",
        "temp": 28,
        "weatherType": "Passing clouds",
        "wind": null,
        "humidity": 94,
        "pressure": 1003,
        "visibility": 21
    },
    {
        "date": "20150801",
        "time": "05:50",
        "temp": 25,
        "weatherType": "Heavy rain More clouds than sun.",
        "wind": 15,
        "humidity": 100,
        "pressure": 995,
        "visibility": 5
   },
...
]

After Epoch 41 there is no change in acc and loss while training the model. And I also feel the prediction is remaining same, regardless of what input I provide. I am training the model with 10 years' weather data of Kolkata. I am certainly expecting better prediction than 'Haze' for any input. Can you please help me choose few things correctly so that the model is able to predict results more accurately? - How many dense layers to use? What should be the config (activation, units and shape) of the dense layers? Which optimizer and loss functions to use while compiling the model?

Someone voted to close this question under 'A community-specific reason'>'Not about programming or software development' category. There is no comment added guiding what makes the voter feel it's not related to programming. Can a moderator please assist?

I voted it up as: it contains code and data.  To paraphrase the question: Is tthe issue with my code, training, or both.

I think main problem here is size of your neural network. The correlation between date and weather should be relatively strong, we call it climate. Knowledge of this correlation was important milestone in ancient agriculture, as far I know. Correlation between today and tomorrow weather could be also somewhat significant, but there are lot of external variables, which can't be obtained from measurements on single station (frontal systems, clouds carried by wind...).
You should be able to find at least some correlation between input and output, but your network just have no space to perform any useful math.
As I'm looking on your network, you have 6 inputs (temp, wind, humidity, pressure, visibility and date), then single neuron connected to those inputs and then some number of output neurons, one for each weather type. This just can't work.
Single artificial neuron is basically just one quite simple math equation. Plus it has internal parameters called weights. The weights are the thing, which is tweaked during training. One for each input plus one extra for threshold. Neuron firstly takes all inputs, multiply each with its weight and sums them together. Result is passed to transfer function, in your case sigmoid. Then the threshold weight is added to this result and it is passed to activation function, in your case just default linear activation a(x) = x. Output of single neuron is single float value.
As you can see, you have decimated all weather info into single float value, which can't hold it. And you are trying to describe all weather correlation basically with equation with just 7 degrees of freedom. Try to experiment with shape and size of your network and maybe you can get better results.
I would also recommend you this tensorflow playgound, where you have just two inputs X and Y and datasets are points of two colors. You can add or remove layers, add neurons on each layer, add data preprocessed by some nonlinear math function (like X squared, sin(Y)...). It's not most useful application for AI, but it's nice and visual, great for learning basics.

I have to agree with @Thugmek, you need to experiment with your neural architecture.  I'm going to put some code to his suggestion:
Thugnek's Suggestion: Add layers plus a few modifications to experiment with
    // add layers to the model
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 64, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [6] }));
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout({ rate: 0.2 })); // Add dropout to prevent overfitting
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 32, activation: 'relu' }));
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout({ rate: 0.2 })); // Add dropout to prevent overfitting

    // softmax because multiclass
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: uniqLabels.length, activation: 'softmax' }));

    // try a better optimizer like adam
    model.compile({
        optimizer: 'adam', // Adam is a robust optimizer over SGD for deep learning
        loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
        metrics: ['accuracy']
    });

